# Is it better to have many measurements each with few data points or few measurements each with many data points?

Tags: experiment-design, simulation, statistical-power

I've wondered this for a long time. Let's say that I'm designing an experiment e.g. to measure human reaction time to images in which the contrast is varied.

If I can afford 1000 trials I could make one of the following:

- 1 condition with 1000 trials.
- 10 conditions each with 100 trials.
- 20 conditions each with 50 trials.
- 100 conditions each with 10 trials.
- 1000 conditions each with 1 trial.

So I can have good estimates in relatively fewer conditions, or noisy estimates but many conditions.

Is there any a priori reason to prefer one of the above trade offs? Maybe it will totally depend on the individual question/experiment/analysis method and require simulation to determine the best choice.

For what it's worth, In my field (cognitive neuroscience) it seems most experiments opt for a few conditions each with many trials.

Comment: If you have a strong signal, you will have high power with few trials, so you can use your remaining budget to address other questions. If your signal is weak, you will need many trials to even address a single question.

Comment: Maybe I would rephrase the title of your question as *Is it better to have many conditions with few observations each or vice-versa?* (or something like that...). In my opinion "measurement" and "data point" are the same thing (although probably they are not...) so your original title doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: In short, you want more measurements of the thing which is more variable.

Comment: This is a very broad and general question which cannot be answered based on the available information. Apart from the signal/noise ratio (@StephanKolassa), you need to worry about the curse of dimensionality, dependencies among your variables, nonlinearities, and probably many more.